# I am not able to access the globally declared variable, on which I am performing an operation in a function, outside the function scope

Tags: javascript

The variable expected_passwd is not accessed after the con.query operation. How can I do the declaration so that I can access it?

```
var uname = req.param('uname');
var passwd = req.param('passwd');
var expected_passwd="";
con.query("select password from signin where uname='"+uname+"'", function (err, result)
{
    if (err){ throw err;}
    expected_passwd=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    expected_passwd=expected_passwd[0].password;
});
console.log(expected_passwd);
```

Comment: the callback function has not been invoked in your code, expected_passwd will be empty string in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a callback function.

```
function getPassword(callback) {
  var req = Request(); // where does this come from?
  var con = Connection(); // where does this come from?
  var uname = req.param('uname');
  var passwd = req.param('passwd');
  var sql = "select password from signin where uname='" + uname + "'";
  con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    var expected_passwd = result[0].password;
    callback(expected_passwd);
  });
}

getPassword(function(pass) {
  console.log(pass); // use the password here!
});
```

There are many things that could be improved with the code but I'll leave that for another question.